# Eclipse no longer able to compile most of the project

Tags: java, eclipse

Not sure what happened. I'm on Eclipse Mars. Friday, everything was fine. Today, it is throwing compiler problems with numerous classes that were definitely compiling fine on the friday.

Every non-compiling class has the following error right at the top with the package declaration: 'Syntax error on token "package", assert expected'. And it's suddenly appeared on hundreds of files. Everything still builds fine via ant.

It's almost like it's using the scrappage compiler for the compilation?

Using eclipse mars and jdk7 on ubuntu 14.04. Any help appreciated.
I've checked the compiler is the right one and set right on the project.

Edit: tried reverting to an earlier install but it didn't work

Edit2: Eventually used fresh install of eclipse, but even then I had to check out a fresh copy from vcs to get it working. Some metadata file somewhere I guess :(

Comment: Have you tried deleting all problems in the 'Problems' view, then doing a clean & build using eclipse?  Restarting eclipse sometimes works too.

Comment: There are literally thousands of problems. I've tried manually deleting the package statement and then readding it on a few files to test. This appears to fix it, but the problem reappears with a restart/clean and build.

Comment: This is most likely a bug in Eclipse. I had the same situation today, fortunately `git stash` and then `git stash apply` fixed it. I hope the Eclipse compiler gets better again, it was so useful in pre Java 8 times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try checking the src directory in java build path of the eclipse project. I remember facing the similar issue long time back because of an issue with src dir.

Comment: It does have the right src directory. It's really strange and annoying :|